# Erro run build nextjs CI False

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, build, next.js

I'm trying to build the nextjs, but this is with the error below. What can it be?I've run the npm run build and it still doesn't work

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mobills-indica",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "yarn build-all",
    "next": "yarn build-firebase && cd \"src/app\" && yarn && yarn dev",
    "preserve": "yarn build-all",
    "serve": "firebase serve",
    "predeploy": "yarn build-all",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy",
    "build-all": "yarn build-next && yarn build-firebase",
    "build-next": "cd \"src/app\" && yarn && yarn build",
    "build-firebase": "cd \"src/functions\" && yarn",
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build"
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mobills-indica@1.0.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mobills-indica@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mobills\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-02T13_10_36_339Z-debug.log
```

Comment: possible to give more info, what command you are using, npm build or anything.

Comment: Hi @dastan, npm build

Answer (score 0):

I might be very late to answer this question but this is what has worked for me and it might help someone to get back on the **development track!**

```
$ npm install -g npm@latest  # or, npm install -g npm@latest --prefix "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
$ rm -rf node_modules        # or, `cmd /c rmdir /s /q node_modules` on Windows
$ npm install
```

**Happy Coding!!!**